# How to retrieve input value before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have to retrieve three input values before submitting so I can use ajax to fill in the form depending on the information inside these boxes.

I first check that the three boxes have text using this script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = false;
    jQuery(".validation").change(function () {
        flag = true;
        jQuery(".validation").each(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).val().trim() == "") {
                flag = false;
            }
        });
        if (flag==true) {
            var calle = jQuery("#calle").val();
            var municipio = jQuery("#municipio").val();
            var provincia = jQuery("#provincia").val();             

            var direccion = calle +","+ municipio +","+ provincia;
            direccion = direccion.replace(/\s/g,'+');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

What I need is that when these three fields have a value to retrieve that value so I can pass it through a URL in PHP before submitting (ajax maybe?)

```
$url =  'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$value .'&sensor=false';
```

**$value** would be the variable (direccion) which is in the script.

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: the url what ur constructing, is that the url of the target php script?

Comment: Can you just use php to get the values?  In your <form> tag, simply state 'method="POST"' or 'method="GET"' (without the single quotes) and make sure you have 'name="your_input_value_name"' for each input.  Then, your PHP script, simply use '$_GET["your_input_value_name"]' or '$_POST["your_input_value_name"]' depending on which method you choose.  This gives you much greater control and will do all the validation on the server side.

Comment: The problem is that the rest of the form has to fill out depending on the information inside these three fields. This means that if I fill in the three fields the rest of the form is filled out before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable as global to access it outside.due to declaring it in change, the scope of variable remains within change function only. so declare the variable outside change event.like this:

```
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var flag = false;
var direccion="";//declare variable
jQuery(".validation").change(function () {
    flag = true;
    jQuery(".validation").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val().trim() == "") {
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    if (flag==true) {
        var calle = jQuery("#calle").val();
        var municipio = jQuery("#municipio").val();
        var provincia = jQuery("#provincia").val();             

        direccion = calle +","+ municipio +","+ provincia;
        direccion = direccion.replace(/\s/g,'+');//define variable on every on change
     }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesnt anwser my question :S

Comment: @MONZTAAA:what exactly do you want??

Answer (score 0):

On your `form` you can add an `onsubmit` attribute which will define an action to take when the form is submitted.
eg :

```
<form method='GET' action='' onsubmit='doAjax();return false;'>
<input type='text' id='inp_name' value='hello'/>
</form>

<script>
function doAjax(){
    alert("this form won't be posted!");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have to do all this without submitting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a ajax call to the url which is constructed

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   var flag = false;
jQuery(".validation").change(function () {
    flag = true;
    var direccio="";
    jQuery(".validation").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val().trim() == "") {
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    if (flag==true) {
        var calle = jQuery("#calle").val();
        var municipio = jQuery("#municipio").val();
        var provincia = jQuery("#provincia").val();             

        direccion = calle +","+ municipio +","+ provincia;
        direccion = direccion.replace(/\s/g,'+');
    }

    $.ajax({
       url: "target.php",
       data:{'value':direccion},
       success: function(response) {
          //process the data received from server script
       });
    });

});
```

**PHP CODE(target.php):**

```
   $value=$_POST['value'];
   $url =  'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$value .'&sensor=false';
   //further processing of data at server end and finally echo the data to client
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with your last desired input tag. Suppose you want data up to the 3rd input tag then you need to Call your custom function in the 3rd input tag with onkeyup="myFunction()"

In myFunction() you can check if the fields are populated or not and can also do the ajax to transfer the data to server